# How Can I change a toolbar icon in a safari app extension at runtime?

Tags: swift, safari-app-extension

I have found this in the documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafaritoolbaritem

which lead me to be able to use the window variable in the toolbarItemClicked function to get a reference to the toolbar item like so.

```
var toolbaritemretrieved = false
window.getToolbarItem { (item) in
            toolbaritem = item! as SFSafariToolbarItem;
            toolbaritemretrieved = true;
        }
```

once I had a reference to the toolbar item I could then run this code and supposedly change the image of the icon.

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "newIcon", ofType: "png")!;
let icon = NSImage(path);
while(!toolbaritemretrieved){
                        //wait for toolbar item to be retrieved
                    }
                    toolbaritem?.setImage(icon);
                    SFSafariApplication.setToolbarItemsNeedUpdate();
```

However this doesn't work. There are no visible errors but for some reason the icon does not display the new image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it turns out that there was actually nothing wrong with my code at this point and I had a forgotten breakpoint.

Comment: Can you please help me in that. I am facing the same problem. Could not able to set the app icon.

Comment: I have created the Safari Extension in xCode project.

Comment: Also, I have other query, like chrome there is function getMainefesto() but how to we can use that in Safari.